# apply share extension module Alfresco automatically(without explicitly selecting and applying)

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-maven, alfresco-enterprise

After every deployment,I have to apply share extension modules explicitly in Alfresco share URL(http://localhost:8081/share/page/modules/deploy).Is there any way these modules get applied in order required(Soon after,as we deploy amps).

Comment: Check <autoDeploy>true</autoDeploy> in the module xml file.

Comment: that worked, since modules are interdependent i needed forced order as well. which worked with this tag  <auto-deploy-index>2 or 3 </auto-deploy-index> , lower the number ,higher the priority

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for enabling auto deployment

```
<autoDeploy>true</autoDeploy>
```

for maintaining order

```
<auto-deploy-index>2</auto-deploy-index>
```

In the share module xml files,lower the number ,higher the priority

Comment: It will be really good if you can add the source of information.Good to know this info as well.

Comment: it is <auto-deploy> and <auto-deploy-index>. The source code that references auto-deploy-index is https://github.com/Alfresco/share/blob/6b3555f30d141f3ebc828aecb090203240e3f085/surf/spring-surf/spring-surf/src/main/java/org/springframework/extensions/surf/ModuleDeploymentService.java#L402